# Why do need this square on the Lenovo B520 monoblock case?

Tags: case, lenovo-desktop-computer

In the instructions, in the description of the elements of the case it is not.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

Comment: Can you post broader photo?

Comment: @MichaelFrank It is difficult to catch it in the frame to be seen. Almost merges with the case. Added some photo.

Comment: It *looks* like it could be for an IR Sensor, but I can't find any info regarding that spot in the Hardware Maintenance Manual.

Comment: Possibly an ambient light sensor for automatic brightness control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a photometric sensor, also known as an ambient light sensor.  It allows the monitor/computer to dynamically adjust the brightness of the display based on the level of light in the room.

From the Lenovo [IdeaCentre B5 Series User Guide](https://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User%27s%20guides%20and%20manuals/B520/IdeaCentre%20B5%20Series%20User%20Guide%20V3.0%20(English).pdf):

> Lenovo Dynamic Brightness System can automatically detect the surrounding 
>   ambient brightness and will adjust display brightness accordingly. You can set the screen brightness to a comfortable level for different environments. You can also set the display delay time to automatically turn off the display when you are away from the computer.

Comment: This is news for me after many years uses. Imagine, for a long time just now I saw him. It's funny) A good mix picked up with the case computer.